# Only one marker showing

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I only have one marker showing on my map even though I have 2 co-ordinates in my XML. What am I missing?

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
<marker> 
<lat>51.615325</lat>
<lng>0.524572</lng>
<icon>flat</icon>
</marker>
<marker><lat>51.60002</lat>
<lng>0.518862</lng>
<icon>house</icon>
</marker>
</markers>
```

My parsing code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;

public class ParserParsing {

private static final String ns = null;
public ArrayList<Entry> parse(InputStream in)
{ 
ArrayList<Entry> list = null;

try {
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(in, null);
parser.nextTag();
list=readFeed(parser);
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
Log.i(".......",list.get(i).lat);
Log.i(".......",list.get(i).lng);
Log.i(".......",list.get(i).icon);
}
} catch(Exception e){

}
return list;
}
private  ArrayList<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

ArrayList<Entry> entry= new ArrayList<Entry>();
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "markers");
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
continue;
}
String name = parser.getName();
Log.i("............",name);
// Starts by looking for the entry tag
if (name.equals("marker")) {
entry.add(readMarker(parser));

} else {
skip(parser);
}
}  
return entry;
}
private Entry readMarker(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "marker");
String lat = null;
String lng = null;
String icon =null;
while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
continue;
}
String name = parser.getName();
Log.i("............",name);
if (name.equals("lat")) {
lat = readLat(parser);
} else if (name.equals("lng")) {
lng = readLng(parser);
else if (name.equals("icon")) {
icon = readIcon(parser);
} 
else {
skip(parser);
}
}
return new Entry(lat,lng,icon);

}
private String readLat(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "lat");
String lat = readText(parser);
parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "lat");
return lat;
}
private String readLng(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "lng");
String lng = readText(parser);
parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "lng");
return lng;
}
private String readIcon(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "icon");
String icon = readText(parser);
parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "icon");
return icon;
}


private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
String result = "";
if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
result = parser.getText();
parser.nextTag();
}
return result;
}
private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
throw new IllegalStateException();
}
int depth = 1;
while (depth != 0) {
switch (parser.next()) {
case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
depth--;
break;
case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
depth++;
break;
}
}
}    
}
```

I know there is something in here that I'm overlooking but cannot figure out what

---

```
01-13 19:37:41.157: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(694): SIOP:: AP = 220, Prev AP = 220, Duration = 10070
01-13 19:37:43.680: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(694): SIOP:: AP = 220 (read only)
01-13 19:37:45.301: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-13 19:37:45.301: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): CheckJNI is OFF
01-13 19:37:45.301: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): setted country_code = UK
01-13 19:37:45.301: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): setted countryiso_code = GB
01-13 19:37:45.311: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): setted sales_code = VOD
01-13 19:37:45.311: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): readGMSProperty: start
01-13 19:37:45.311: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
01-13 19:37:45.311: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): readGMSProperty: end
01-13 19:37:45.311: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): addProductProperty: start
01-13 19:37:45.321: D/dalvikvm(11095): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:45.331: D/dalvikvm(11095): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:45.341: D/dalvikvm(11095): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:45.341: D/dalvikvm(11095): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:45.631: D/dalvikvm(11095): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 176 unimplemented (abstract) methods
01-13 19:37:45.712: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-13 19:37:45.732: D/AndroidRuntime(11095): Shutting down VM
01-13 19:37:45.742: D/dalvikvm(11095): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-13 19:37:46.262: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(694): SIOP:: AP = 220 (read only)
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): CheckJNI is OFF
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): setted country_code = UK
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): setted countryiso_code = GB
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): setted sales_code = VOD
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): readGMSProperty: start
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): readGMSProperty: already setted!!
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): readGMSProperty: end
01-13 19:37:46.292: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): addProductProperty: start
01-13 19:37:46.302: D/dalvikvm(11106): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:46.312: D/dalvikvm(11106): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:46.322: D/dalvikvm(11106): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:46.322: D/dalvikvm(11106): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
01-13 19:37:46.622: D/dalvikvm(11106): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 176 unimplemented (abstract) methods
01-13 19:37:46.692: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-13 19:37:46.743: I/power(694): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1350000 
01-13 19:37:46.743: D/SSRMv2:CustomFrequencyManagerService(694): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1350000  uid : 1000  pid : 694  pkgName : ACTIVITY_RESUME_BOOSTER@6
01-13 19:37:46.753: W/ActivityManager(694): mDVFSHelper.acquire()
01-13 19:37:46.763: D/WindowManager(694): computeScreenConfigurationLocked() set config.orientation=1 dw=1080 dh=1920 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokensLocked:5171 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokens:5142 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked:1018 
01-13 19:37:46.763: D/PowerManagerService(694): setKeyboardVisibility: false
01-13 19:37:46.773: E/MP-Decision(1743): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.400000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 70
01-13 19:37:46.773: E/MP-Decision(1743): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
01-13 19:37:46.773: D/SurfaceWidgetClient(24114): [123491/11] SurfaceWidgetClient onTrimMemory level: 20
01-13 19:37:46.783: D/LockPatternUtils(694): isPcwEnable = null
01-13 19:37:46.783: D/AndroidRuntime(11106): Shutting down VM
01-13 19:37:46.783: D/jdwp(11106): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
01-13 19:37:46.783: D/dalvikvm(11106): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-13 19:37:46.823: D/AbsListView(10561): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-13 19:37:46.823: I/SurfaceFlinger(206): id=4904 Removed Mauncher (0/5)
01-13 19:37:46.823: D/AbsListView(10561): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
01-13 19:37:46.823: D/AbsListView(10561): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Marker code

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("markers.xml");
} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}

ArrayList<Entry> entries= (ArrayList<Entry>) new ParserParsing().parse(is);
Double latitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(0).lat);
Double longitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(0).lng);
String icon = entries.get(0).icon;
LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(lng)
.title(icon)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName()))));
```

Comment: post the log cat. what does this log `Log.i(".......",list.get(i).lat);`

Comment: I have just tried to filter the LogCat for the above but nothing is showing

Comment: it should work. there is nothing wrong in the code

Comment: That's what I thought, the code works perfect but it only shows one or the other coordinate it very strange, the only thing i can think is the icon line is causing it to not work

Comment: nope it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: then im at a loss as everything is perfect

Comment: i don't see even any marker value (not even one) in log. are you sure the this is correct log?. So i believe you get all values. But you are using list.get(0). means index o only

Comment: also don't post updates to question as an answer it will be deleted eventually

Comment: Yes it is the log, I even cleared it to make sure

Comment: i don't see any of the values. so i guess its not the log. re- run and get the updated log. i am pretty sure the code is fine

Comment: perhaps the icon is beyond the viewport of the map?

Comment: @Android-converter post the code where you show the marker the problem is not parsing. its the way you show your marker

Comment: I have just re-run the app and still not getting any errors for the Log.i

Comment: @Android-converter the parsing is 100% fine tested myself. So the problem lies in the way you show marker. so what you are saying is either wrong or you need to post your marker code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.the_map)).getMap();
ArrayList<Entry> entries= (ArrayList<Entry>) new ParserParsing().parse(is);
for(int i=0;i>entries.size();i++)
{
Double latitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(i).lat);
Double longitude = Double.valueOf(entries.get(i).lng);
String icon = entries.get(i).icon;
LatLng lng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(lng)
.title(icon)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(icon, "drawable", getPackageName()))));
}
```

Comment: Change my code to that and my app stopped running: with error: Unfortunately app has stopped

Comment: @Android-converter post the logcat. there are 2 items index 0 and index 1 make use of it properly. this has nothing to do with parsing.

Comment: This is the logcat that is all that is in there 01-13 20:52:15.099: E/AndroidRuntime(21381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 20:52:15.099: E/AndroidRuntime(21381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mhmedia.fuelfinder/com.mhmedia.fuelfinder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 20:52:15.099: E/AndroidRuntime(21381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
01-13 20:52:15.099: E/AndroidRuntime(21381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)

Comment: @Android-converter post the stacktrace full by editing your question

Comment: @Android-converter your new question code is not the one you copied from my post. makes sense. also you din't post the full stack trace for me to help further.

Comment: -I couldn't get my stacktrace exported, but I realised that I did'nt fully copy your posts as it's your code not mine (hence why it didn't work)